# What is the proper semantic markup for a statistical graph with view controls alongside

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

I try to redo the markup of a one pager incorporating html5 elements. The key element of the page is a graph with logarithmic curves per country on the left and on the right the view controls to alter what and how things are displayed in the graph on the left. My initial thought was:

```
<main>
 <article></article>
 <aside></aside>
</main>
```

`main` wrapping the key content of the page - the graph and its view controls. I chose `article` for the graph cuz it is a [self contained composition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) and the `aside` for the view controls cuz its content is [indirectly related to the main content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside). The choice of the `aside` is due to the lack of some sort of dedicated element for a view control in html5 (at least I am not aware of any proper). 
Problem with this solution is that Wave Tools pointed out that wrapping an `aside` inside the `main` element isn't recommended best practice and should be avoided if possible. My second choice then was:

```
<div>
 <main></main>
 <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Then I got the objection and feedback that `aside` is only suited for additional related information and not in the context of view controls. So I am a bit out of ideas what would be the cleanest and semantic proper way to markup that setup? Maybe that way?

```
<main>
 <article></article>
 <div></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a purely HTML perspective (i.e. not including WAI-ARIA) you are over complicating this problem for yourself.

The controls are related so an `<aside>` is not appropriate. Changing a control changes the graph.

In this case all you need is `<section>` elements.

However although the HTML may be simple, the WAI-ARIA and associated focus management etc. is a little bit more involved. I have added a decent amount of information below to get you started but it is by no means a complete example.

### Rough example of appropriate HTML and WAI-ARIA

```css
/*styling is just for demonstration, it is not relevant to the functionality*/
section.left{
    width: 58%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
}
section.right{
    width: 38%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
}
#graph{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25vw;
    background-color: #666;
    outline: 2px solid red;
}
label, input{
   display: block;
   padding: 0.5rem;
}
section{
   outline: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!--without seeing your actual page it is hard to know whether you should use role="figure" so you will need to research that yourself.-->
  <!--it should also be noted that if your site supports IE8 you should use `aria-label="heading 2 title"` instead of `aria-labelledby`.-->
  <section class="left" role="figure" aria-labelledby="graph-title">
    <h2 id="graph-title">Graph of country information</h2>
    <div id="graph"></div>
  </section>
  <!--toolbar is the best fit for explaining what the controls are. You should also use `aria-controls="IDofElement"` to associate it to your graph (you will need to double check this in a screen reader as it is intended for use on textareas but I don't see why it won't work for an accessible graph / chart.).-->
  <section class="right" role="toolbar" aria-controls="graph" aria-labelledby="controls-section" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <h2 id="controls-section">Graph Controls</h2>
    <label for="input1">graph x value</label>
    <input id="input1"/>
    <label for="input2">graph y value</label>
    <input id="input2"/>
  </section>
</main>
```

#### Explanation of example

You will notice that the HTML itself is very simple.

Just two regions with appropriate headings.

This will make it pretty accessible by itself as the headings indicate clearly what each section is for.

However we can add some WAI-ARIA attributes to improve things in screen readers that support them.

**First** we label the sections.

This is useful as some screen reader users prefer to navigate / explore a page via sections.

Other users prefer to explore a page via headings (majority of users actually).

By using `aria-labelledby` and pointing to the heading we cover both of these bases. (for maximum backwards compatibility you should actually use `aria-label="same text as the heading"` and `role="contentinfo"` on a region for it to work on IE8 and below but I only support to IE9 and up).

**Next** we add appropriate WAI-ARIA roles to each section. I have assumed the [figure role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Figure_Role) is appropriate for the graph. but you will have to decide that based on your use case.

For the controls for the graph we give that section the [role of "toolbar"](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#toolbar). We then make it clear that the controls in that section are related to the graph with [`aria-controls`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-controls).

Now yet again I cannot see your graph so it may be (and is quite likely) more appropriate to use [`aria-owns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-owns) on your toolbar.

**Finally** we add `aria-orientation="vertical"` as that is a attribute that is applicable to `role="toolbar"` when controls are stacked.

**Please note** that you will probably have to add focus management etc. yourself. See [the W3C toolbar example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/toolbar/toolbar.html) for ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that profound explanation! and you are totally right I was overcomplicating the problem in my effort to simply use the base set of html5 elements. A good lesson to read up more wai-aria extending the markup with those attributes. For context the page I try help to improve is https://aatishb.com/covidtrends/ . I read up on the roles and would go with `role="figure"`. That seem to fit: `A figure is generally considered to be one or more images, code snippets, or other content that puts across information in a different way to a regular flow of text.`

Comment: And about the `aria-controls` reading the spec `aria-controls` seems to be the more appropriate fit since the graph is the element whose contents or presences are controlled by the sidebar. also one of the given examples hits the spot: `A group of checkboxes may control what commodity prices are tracked live in a table or graph.` Thanks again will read up more in the wai-aria field. I've neglected it for too long!

Comment: not a problem. I think you have most stuff sorted after a glance at the page (sorry I will try and look properly for you later.) One final thing to consider is allow a way to switch off animations on the graphs for people who have a movement disorder. Maybe look at `prefers-reduced-motion` media query there. Good luck!